# wrap-word does not work on v-list-item-title/subtitle

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify [`v-list`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists) component.
I have a bit longer text to display within the `v-list-item-subtitle` component. This text is not fully visible:

[image]

To avoid this issue, I used what I use in similar situations successfully: I opt to apply a class with the CSS property [`word-wrap`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) set to `break-word`:

```css
.wrap-text {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

used this way:

```html
<v-list-item-subtitle v-html="item.subtitle" class="wrap-text"></v-list-item-subtitle>
```

This does not fix the issue. I noticed the same behavior when I use `v-list-item-title`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/begueradj-the-sasster/pen/BayOZWJ)

Comment: what are you trying to do, thats unclear from the question.

Comment: seems to be cause by `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [`webkit-line-clamp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) property on the `v-list-item__subtitle`. Try

```css
.wrap-text {
  -webkit-line-clamp: unset !important;
}
```

For `v-list-item__title` use `white-space: normal;`

Answer (score 6):

I am using Vuetify but the above answers didn't work for me. But `white-space: normal;` worked.

```
.wrap-text {
   white-space: normal;
}
```

add the class to `v-list-item-substitle` component.

```
<v-list-item-subtitle v-html="item.subtitle" class="wrap-text"></v-list-item-subtitle>
```